# Compilation Failure on Java + Kotlin SpringBoot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm in the process of adding `Kotlin` support to my `Java Spring Boot` application. My edits to the `pom.xml` file are as below:

For the dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.71</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.71</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

and the plugins:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <version>1.3.61</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerPlugins>
                    <plugin>spring</plugin>
                </compilerPlugins>
                <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDir>
                        </sourceDirs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</sourceDir>
                        </sourceDirs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-compile</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-testCompile</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>java-compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>java-test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
     </plugin>
```

My configuration seems to be correct, however, when trying to run the project, I encounter the following error:

```
[ERROR] java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class 

org.jetbrains.kotlin.allopen.AllOpenCommandLineProcessor does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void processOption(org.jetbrains.kotlin.compiler.plugin.AbstractCliOption, java
.lang.String, org.jetbrains.kotlin.config.CompilerConfiguration)' of interface org.jetbrains.kotlin.compiler.plugin.CommandLineProcessor.
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.plugins.PluginCliParser.processPluginOptions(PluginCliParser.kt:117)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.plugins.PluginCliParser.loadPlugins(PluginCliParser.kt:73)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.plugins.PluginCliParser.loadPluginsSafe(PluginCliParser.kt:45)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.loadPlugins(K2JVMCompiler.kt:239)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:73)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:55)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:84)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:42)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:104)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.KotlinCompileMojoBase.execCompiler(KotlinCompileMojoBase.java:228)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.K2JVMCompileMojo.execCompiler(K2JVMCompileMojo.java:237)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.K2JVMCompileMojo.execCompiler(K2JVMCompileMojo.java:55)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.KotlinCompileMojoBase.execute(KotlinCompileMojoBase.java:209)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.K2JVMCompileMojo.execute(K2JVMCompileMojo.java:222)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:122)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main(MavenWrapperMain.java:61)
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not mix Kotlin versions. Your plugin uses 1.3.61 but your sdk refers to 1.2.71. Consider using a property:

```
<properties>
    <kotlin.version>1.3.61</kotlin.version>
</properties>
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    ....
</dependencies>
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            ...
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: My next guess is that your byte code does not refer the right jdk. Does your JAVA_HOME point to a 1.8 JDK? If it does i think the Kotlin compiler does not hav the right api. Try an additional property `<kotlin.compiler.languageVersion>1.3</kotlin.compiler.languageVersion>`. The Kotlin api and language version must match.

Comment: In case you not already using it: the official kotlin  [guide](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html) is pretty well documented.